# How to use RXTX for java in a javafx application

Tags: java, javafx, arduino, scenebuilder, rxtx

i need to read the input from the textfield from my application and sending it to arduino. I can read the value but i don't know how to send it to arduino. I have a Arduino class that should read and write on the serial port, but how can i send the amp value to Arduino?

> JavaFX class

```
private String frequenza;
private String ampiezza;
@FXML private TextField amp;
@FXML private TextField freq;
private Stage stageiniziale;
private BorderPane rootlayout;
Arduino a = new Arduino();


@Override    
public void start(Stage stageiniziale){
this.stageiniziale = stageiniziale;
this.stageiniziale.setTitle("App Luca");

initRootLayout();
mostraPersona();



}



public void initRootLayout(){
try{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(ArduinoSeriale.class.getResource("Root.fxml"));
    rootlayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

    Scene scene= new Scene(rootlayout);
    stageiniziale.setScene(scene);
    stageiniziale.show();
    a.initialize();
}


catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}



public void mostraPersona() {
    try {
        // Load person overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(ArduinoSeriale.class.getResource("Principale.fxml"));
        AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
        rootlayout.setCenter(personOverview);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return stageiniziale;
} 


public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}

public void bottoneFrequenza() {
  frequenza = getFrequenza();
  System.out.println(frequenza);
}

public void bottoneAmpiezza() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  ampiezza = getAmpiezza();
   int amp = Integer.parseInt(ampiezza);
   System.out.println(amp);
}

public String getFrequenza(){
frequenza = freq.getText();
return frequenza;
}

public String getAmpiezza(){
ampiezza = amp.getText();
return ampiezza;
}
```

> Arduino Class ( RXTX )

```
SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
        "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                    "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
        "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
        "COM5", // Windows
};
/**
* A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
* converting the bytes into characters 
* making the displayed results codepage independent
*/
private BufferedReader input;
/** The output stream to the port */
private OutputStream output;
/** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
/** Default bits per second for COM port. */
private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

public void initialize() {
            // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
            // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
           // System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        // set port parameters
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        // open the streams
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

        // add event listeners
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * This should be called when you stop using the port.
 * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
 */
public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
 * @param oEvent
 */
@Override
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    try {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        //serialPort.getOutputStream().write(1);
        serialPort.getOutputStream().write(1);
        //Thread.sleep(20);

        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Arduino.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}

    public synchronized void invia(int a) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
     serialPort.getOutputStream().write(1);
     //Thread.sleep(20);
     System.out.println(a);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Arduino main = new Arduino();
    main.initialize();
    Thread t=new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
            //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
            try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        }
    };
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Started");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should have been a comment, but I don't have the reputations to write a comment, so adding an answer

1)Your write method is within the serialEvent method, so it will write only if you receive some data. Since you are receiving the data , this is what I would suggest.

In the initialize() method you have already initialized

```
output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
```

so you need not repeat this in the void serialEvent method.

You can write your amp value[ assuming getAmpiezza() returns the correct amp value and is properly imported] in the following manner

```
output.write(getAmpiezza().getBytes());
output.flush();
```

Have you tried this yet? If not, please do and reply. If yes, what was the problem?

Thanks